How to use Keras_tuner() for Mask-RCNN (matterport implementation) Hyperparameter tuning?
I am trying to use keras_tuner to tune hyperparameters of a Mask-RCNN model ( a fork from matterport implementation).
The question is simply how to do Hyperparameter tuning for matterport Mask-RCNN model using keras_tuner?
I created following functions and then followed the introduced procedure to run the tuner.search() which runs and performs the trials but in the third trial leads to the error message:
Trial 2 Complete [00h 00m 09s]

Best loss So Far: None
Total elapsed time: 00h 00m 17s

Search: Running Trial #3

Value             |Best Value So Far |Hyperparameter
0.00010336        |0.0023794         |lr
0.80384           |0.92497           |momentum
0.00011279        |0.00035505        |weight_decay

but then:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 tuner.search(train_data_generator, validation_data=valid_data_generator)#, epochs=4, steps_per_epoch=4, validation_steps=2, max_queue_size=100)

File c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\base_tuner.py:235, in BaseTuner.search(self, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    233     self.on_trial_begin(trial)
    234     self._try_run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
--> 235     self.on_trial_end(trial)
    236 self.on_search_end()

File c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\base_tuner.py:339, in BaseTuner.on_trial_end(self, trial)
    333 def on_trial_end(self, trial):
    334     """Called at the end of a trial.
    335 
    336     Args:
    337         trial: A `Trial` instance.
    338     """
--> 339     self.oracle.end_trial(trial)
    340     self.save()

File c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\oracle.py:108, in synchronized.<locals>.wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    106     LOCKS[oracle].acquire()
    107     THREADS[oracle] = thread_name
--> 108 ret_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
    109 if need_acquire:
    110     THREADS[oracle] = None

File c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\oracle.py:588, in Oracle.end_trial(self, trial)
    586 if not self._retry(trial):
    587     self.end_order.append(trial.trial_id)
--> 588     self._check_consecutive_failures()
    590 self._save_trial(trial)
    591 self.save()

File c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\oracle.py:545, in Oracle._check_consecutive_failures(self)
    543     consecutive_failures = 0
    544 if consecutive_failures == self.max_consecutive_failed_trials:
--> 545     raise RuntimeError(
    546         "Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit "
    547         f"of {self.max_consecutive_failed_trials}.\n"
    548         + (trial.message or "")
    549     )

RuntimeError: Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit of 3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\base_tuner.py", line 274, in _try_run_and_update_trial
    self._run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\base_tuner.py", line 239, in _run_and_update_trial
    results = self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\tuner.py", line 314, in run_trial
    obj_value = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, *args, **copied_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\tuner.py", line 233, in _build_and_fit_model
    results = self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\hypermodel.py", line 149, in fit
    return model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training_v1.py", line 856, in fit
    return func.fit(
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training_generator_v1.py", line 647, in fit
    return fit_generator(
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training_generator_v1.py", line 225, in model_iteration
    model.reset_metrics()
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training_v1.py", line 1075, in reset_metrics
    m.reset_state()
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras\src\metrics\base_metric.py", line 265, in reset_state
    backend.batch_set_value([(v, 0) for v in self.variables])
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "c:\Users\anedaeij23\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\mrcnn-tunner-tf214-p31012\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 4340, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

plesae notice the last line:
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

What I did:
import keras
import keras_tuner
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import re
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Root directory of the project
#ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("../../")
CODE_DIR = os.path.abspath("../")
DATA_ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("Y:/Results/Images/dataset/")
# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(CODE_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn import model as modellib
from teeth import teeth


# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(CODE_DIR, "logs")

# Path to Ballon trained weights
# You can download this file from the Releases page
# https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/releases
COCO_WEIGHTS_PATH = os.path.join(CODE_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")



def build_dataset(config,dataset_path = 'Y:/Results/Images/dataset', augmentation = None):
    # Training dataset.
    dataset_train = teeth.TeethDataset()
    dataset_train.load_teeth(dataset_path, "train")
    dataset_train.prepare()

    # Validation dataset
    dataset_val = teeth.TeethDataset()
    dataset_val.load_teeth(dataset_path, "val")
    dataset_val.prepare()
    
            # Data generators
    train_generator = modellib.DataGenerator(dataset_train, config, shuffle=True,
                                        augmentation= augmentation)
    val_generator = modellib.DataGenerator(dataset_train, config, shuffle=True)
    
    return train_generator, val_generator



def call_existing_code(lr, momentum, weights_path,weight_dacay, layers = 'heads'):

    config = teeth.TeethConfig()
    config.LEARNING_RATE = lr
    config.LEARNING_MOMENTUM = momentum
    config.WEIGHT_DECAY = weight_dacay

    model = teeth.modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="training", config=config,
                                  model_dir=MODEL_DIR)
    
    # model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True, exclude=[
    #                                                 "mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc",
    #                                                 "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])
    layer_regex = {
        # all layers but the backbone
        "heads": r"(mrcnn\_.*)|(rpn\_.*)|(fpn\_.*)",
        # From a specific Resnet stage and up
        "3+": r"(res3.*)|(bn3.*)|(res4.*)|(bn4.*)|(res5.*)|(bn5.*)|(mrcnn\_.*)|(rpn\_.*)|(fpn\_.*)",
        "4+": r"(res4.*)|(bn4.*)|(res5.*)|(bn5.*)|(mrcnn\_.*)|(rpn\_.*)|(fpn\_.*)",
        "5+": r"(res5.*)|(bn5.*)|(mrcnn\_.*)|(rpn\_.*)|(fpn\_.*)",
        # All layers
        "all": ".*",
    }
    if layers in layer_regex.keys():
        layers = layer_regex[layers]

    
    model.set_trainable(layers)
    model.compile(learning_rate = config.LEARNING_RATE, momentum=config.LEARNING_MOMENTUM)
    
    return model.keras_model



def build_model(hp):
    lr = hp.Float("lr", min_value=1e-4, max_value=1e-2, sampling="log")
    momentum = hp.Float("momentum", min_value=0.8, max_value=1, sampling="log")
    wd = hp.Float("weight_decay", min_value=8e-5, max_value=1e-3, sampling="log")
    # call existing model-building code with the hyperparameter values.
    keras_model = call_existing_code(lr=lr, momentum=momentum , weights_path=COCO_WEIGHTS_PATH, weight_dacay=wd)
    return keras_model



hp = keras_tuner.HyperParameters()
config = teeth.TeethConfig()
train_data_generator, valid_data_generator = build_dataset(config)

tuner = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    hypermodel=build_model,
    objective='loss',#"val_accuracy",
    max_trials=5,
    executions_per_trial=2,
    overwrite=True,
    directory="my_dir",
    project_name="helloworld",
)

tuner.search(train_data_generator, validation_data=valid_data_generator)


I think it is important to notice internal mrcnn compile function structure. This is the function that I use to compile in call_existing_code():

def compile(self, learning_rate, momentum):
"""Gets the model ready for training. Adds losses, regularization, and
metrics. Then calls the Keras compile() function.
"""
# Optimizer object
optimizer = keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD(
#optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(
    lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum,
    clipnorm=self.config.GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM)
# Add Losses
loss_names = [
    "rpn_class_loss",  "rpn_bbox_loss",
    "mrcnn_class_loss", "mrcnn_bbox_loss", "mrcnn_mask_loss"]
for name in loss_names:
    layer = self.keras_model.get_layer(name)
    if layer.output in self.keras_model.losses:
        continue
    loss = (
        tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=layer.output, keepdims=True)
        * self.config.LOSS_WEIGHTS.get(name, 1.))
    #print("compile > loss: ", loss)#Arash
    self.keras_model.add_loss(loss)

# Add L2 Regularization
# Skip gamma and beta weights of batch normalization layers.
#self.keras_model.trainable_weights#Arash
reg_losses = [
    keras.regularizers.l2(self.config.WEIGHT_DECAY)(w) / tf.cast(tf.size(input=w), tf.float32)
    for w in self.keras_model.trainable_weights
    if 'gamma' not in w.name and 'beta' not in w.name]

self.keras_model.add_loss(tf.add_n(reg_losses))

# Compile
self.keras_model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=[None] * len(self.keras_model.outputs))

# Add metrics for losses
for name in loss_names:
    if name in self.keras_model.metrics_names:
        continue
    layer = self.keras_model.get_layer(name)
    self.keras_model.metrics_names.append(name)
    loss = (
        tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=layer.output, keepdims=True)
        * self.config.LOSS_WEIGHTS.get(name, 1.))
    self.keras_model.add_metric(loss, name=name, aggregation='mean')


